# button color onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, button

I have 3 buttons which are green i want to change the color to red when there is clicked on the button for example: you click on button 1 the button goes from green to red then you click on button 2 and button 1 changes back to green and now button 2 is red.

right now i have:

```
 var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
    var count= 0;
    
    button1.onclick = onbutton1clicked;
    
    function onbutton1clicked(){
        count++;
        button1.innerHTML=count;
        
        if(onbutton1clicked){
            button1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }else{
            button1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }

  var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
  var count= 0;
    
    button2.onclick = onbutton2clicked;
    
    function onbutton2clicked(){
        count++;
        button2.innerHTML=count;
        
        if(onbutton2clicked){
            button2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }else{
            button2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }

  var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");
  var count= 0;
    
    button3.onclick = onbutton3clicked;
    
    function onbutton3clicked(){
        count++;
        button3.innerHTML=count;
        
        if(onbutton3clicked){
            button3.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }else{
            button3.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }
```

but when clicking on an other button the first pressed button stay red how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the other buttons again:

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var count = 0;

button1.onclick = onbutton1clicked;

function onbutton1clicked() {
  count++;
  button1.innerHTML = count;

  if (onbutton1clicked) {
    button1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    button2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    button3.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    button1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}

var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
var count = 0;

button2.onclick = onbutton2clicked;

function onbutton2clicked() {
  count++;
  button2.innerHTML = count;

  if (onbutton2clicked) {
    button1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    button2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    button3.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    button2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}

var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");
var count = 0;

button3.onclick = onbutton3clicked;

function onbutton3clicked() {
  count++;
  button3.innerHTML = count;

  if (onbutton3clicked) {
    button1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    button2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    button3.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    button3.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

```css
button{
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">1</button>
<button id="button2">2</button>
<button id="button3">3</button>
```

I didn't modify the rest of your code it's too confusing

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question you have got here :D

First of all before answering your question, I believe it a good idea to just point that it always a good practice. To write code in a way that is understandable and concise even just for yourself a great habit that if formed from early on will save you a lot of stress and debugging hours in the future :3

With that being said here is the solution.

```js
  var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
            var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
            var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");
            var count = 0;

            button1.onclick = onbutton1clicked;
            button2.onclick = onbutton2clicked;
            button3.onclick = onbutton3clicked;

            function isRed(button) {
                if (button.style.backgroundColor === "red") {
                    return "green";
                } else {
                    return "red";
                }
            }

            function onbutton1clicked() {
                button1.innerHTML = count++;
                button1.style.backgroundColor = isRed(button1);
                button2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                button3.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }

            function onbutton2clicked() {
                button2.innerHTML = count++;
                button1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                button2.style.backgroundColor = isRed(button2);
                button3.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }

            function onbutton3clicked() {
                button3.innerHTML = count++;
                button1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                button2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                button3.style.backgroundColor = isRed(button3);
            }
```

```css
button {
  background-color: green;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Hello There</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="button1">0</button>
        <button id="button2">0</button>
        <button id="button3">0</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

What you were missing in your answer is that within your `if` statement your only changing the color to red once it been clicked. So that means every time you do click the button it will always change to red and have no way of changing to any other color.

Simply by checking what color the current button is in, is a more effective approach, with this you just check what color the current button is in. And just change it accordingly !

I believe this the functionality you want ? Please let me know if I missed something !

Wish you a great day :D

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, you can use an active Class. It's shorter and more readable (in my ow opinion).

I get the reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp) and modified it.

Here's the example:

HTML:

```
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn active">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the active class (and buttons on mouse-over) */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDIV");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}`
```

You can see the live demo [HERE](https://codepen.io/hisamafahri/pen/zVLdGb)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('button')];
        let count=0;
        buttons.forEach(b => {
            b.innerText=count;
            b.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                buttons.forEach(b=>b.style.backgroundColor="red")
                b.style.backgroundColor = b.style.backgroundColor == 'green' ? 'red' : 'green';
                b.innerText=++count;
            })
        });
```

```css
 button{
    background: red;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 50px;
    color: white;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
   </body>
</html>
```